# Code help, can't get binary tree

Tags: java, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, postfix-notation

So my goal is turn some sort of expression into a postfix expression (check), and then convert that expression into a binary tree. Here is my main class

```
public class ConvertIntoTree 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // Create a new InfixToPostfix expression from input
        InfixtoPostfix mystack = new InfixtoPostfix(15);
        System.out.println("Type in an expression like (1+2)*(3+4)/(12-5) //No spaces ");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = scan.next();
        System.out.println("The Expression you have typed in infix form :\n"+str);
        System.out.println("The Expression in Postfix is :\n"+mystack.InToPost(str));

        ExpressionTree expressionTree = new ExpressionTree(str);
        expressionTree.createExpressionTree();
        //expressionTree.prefix();
        System.out.println("The Expression I want");
        expressionTree.infix();        
    }

}
```

and here is my expression tree class

```
class ExpressionTree {

    private final String postfix;
    private TreeNode root;

    /**
     * Takes in a valid postfix expression and later its used to construct the expression tree.
     * The posfix expression, if invalid, leads to invalid results 
     * 
     * @param postfix   the postfix expression.
     */
    public ExpressionTree(String postfix) {
        if (postfix == null) { throw new NullPointerException("The posfix should not be null"); }
        if (postfix.length() == 0)  { throw new IllegalArgumentException("The postfix should not be empty"); } 
        this.postfix = postfix;
    }

    private static class TreeNode {
        TreeNode left;
        char ch;
        TreeNode right;

        TreeNode(TreeNode left, char ch, TreeNode right) {
            this.left = left;
            this.ch = ch;
            this.right = right;
        }
    }


    private boolean isOperator(char c) {
        return c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '*' || c == '/';
    }


    /**
     * Constructs an expression tree, using the postfix expression
     */
    public void createExpressionTree() {
        final Stack<TreeNode> nodes = new Stack<TreeNode>();
        for (int i = 0; i < postfix.length(); i++) {
            char ch  = postfix.charAt(i);
            if (isOperator(ch)) {
               TreeNode rightNode = nodes.pop();
               TreeNode leftNode = nodes.pop();
               nodes.push(new TreeNode(leftNode, ch, rightNode));
            } else {
                nodes.add(new TreeNode(null, ch, null));
            }
        }
        root = nodes.pop();
    }


    /**
     * Returns the prefix notation
     * 
     * @return the prefix notation
     */
    public String prefix() {
        if (root == null) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("The root is empty, the tree has not yet been constructed.");
        }

        final StringBuilder prefix = new StringBuilder();
        preOrder(root, prefix);
        return prefix.toString();
    }

    private void preOrder(TreeNode node, StringBuilder prefix) {
        if (node != null) {
            prefix.append(node.ch);
            preOrder(node.left, prefix);
            preOrder(node.right, prefix);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the infix expression
     * 
     * @return  the string of infix.
     */
    public String infix() {
        if (root == null) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("The root is empty, the tree has not yet been constructed.");
        }
        final StringBuilder infix = new StringBuilder();
        inOrder(root, infix);
        return infix.toString();
    }

    private void inOrder(TreeNode node, StringBuilder infix) {
        if (node != null) {
            inOrder(node.left, infix);
            infix.append(node.ch);
            inOrder(node.right, infix);
        }

    }

}
```

After I run `expressionTree.infix();`, nothing. Obviously I'm doing something wrong. Any ideas or help, thanks.

Comment: I'd suggest trying a debugger - e.g. from Eclipse. This ought to give you an idea as to what's actually going on when your code is running and from this you'll be able to deduce what's gone wrong.

Comment: How about printing the return value of infix ?

Comment: what is InfixtoPostfix ?

Comment: @guillaumegirod-vitouchkina It's my class that turns the infix expression to a postfix expression, it's rather lengthy and works so i thought i should exlcude it.

Comment: @JFPicard yeah not sure where my head was at, just did and still more problems... yay!

Answer (score 0):

After a little tinkering, the main issue was using `expressionTree2.infix()`
instead of `System.out.println(expressionTree2.infix());`